# Spring advice is getting called in tomcat but not working in jboss

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have a spring project in which i am applying an aspect before RequestMapping Annotation within Controller Class. i have tested the same in tomcat there was no issue but while i am writing the same code in jboss aop call is getting skipped.

the expression for pointcut is :

```java
@Pointcut(" within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)  && @annotation(requestMapping) && execution(public * *(..))")
```

web.xml

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring_config/springreport-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring_config/application-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

springreport-servlet.xml

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.*"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Comment: The `within` construct is wrong. Could you please update the question with complete code that works ?

Comment: Why would the `within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)` construct be wrong? Of course it would be easier and more canonical to replace it by `@within(org.springframework.stereotype.Controller)`, but I would not call it wrong.

Comment: @kriegaex My mistake then , my understanding of specifying a type using `within` was different.